# Spring does not autowire beans with JAX-WS webservice end points

Tags: spring, jax-ws, autowired

I am trying to consume a **JAX-WS webservice** written by me. I always get `nullPointerException` for spring autowired annotated beans. However, everything works fine within serverSide over web, but accessing beans through **JAX-WS webservice**.

I have tried by extending `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`, but still no luck. How can I do this.

regards, Rohit

Comment: Do you get null objects inside your webService class while autowiring them? Or you get null for webservice, autowired somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I had no experience extending SpringBeanAutowiringSupport but had successfuly used this approach:

1. Annotate webService class such a way :

   ```
   @Component("yourWebService")  
   @WebService(endpointInterface ="your.package.YourServicePort")
   ```
2. Create new spring-context xml for webService and define JAX-WS endpoint :

   ```
   <jaxws:endpoint
       id="yourServiceEndpoint"
       implementor="#yourWebService"
       address="${yourWebService.wsdl.url}"> //load url from properties file
   </jaxws:endpoint>
   ```
3. I suppose you know how to use props in spring, but will explain just in case. You should also create `yourWebService.properties` file and define it in spring context to use this construction `${yourWebService.wsdl.url}` :

   ```
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
         <list>
             <value>yourWebService.properties</value>
         </list>
      </property>
   ```

Using this approach I had successfuly used JAX with Spring

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I already have <endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
    version="2.0">

    <endpoint name="TransactionWebServicImpl"
        implementation="com.qiib.service.TransactionImpl"
        url-pattern="/transaction" />
</endpoints> and I gave @Component("TransactionImpl")  
@WebService
public interface Transaction {